# Math functions returning zero in OpenGL program

Tags: c, opengl

I already know none of you is going to be able to replicate this bug but I don't even know what to try anymore. This is the code:

```
void Arrow2D(double x, double y, double x2, double y2, double width) {
    double deltaX = x2 - x;
    double deltaY = y2 - y;
    double angle = atan2(deltaY, deltaX) * 180 / 3.14;
    double heightArrow = sqrt(deltaX*deltaX + deltaY*deltaY);
    printf("height = sqrt(%f) = %f\n", deltaX*deltaX + deltaY*deltaY, heightArrow);
    /*glPushMatrix(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glRotatef(angle, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

    //glTranslatef(200, 200, 0);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2f(-width/2, 20);
    glVertex2f(-width/2, 0);
    glVertex2f(width/2, 0);
    glVertex2f(width/2, 20);
    glEnd();
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glVertex2f(-width/1.2, 20);
    glVertex2f(+width/1.2, 20);
    glVertex2f(0, 30);
    glEnd();

    glPopMatrix(GL_MODELVIEW);*/
```

}

Now, if the second part is commented the value of the variable `heightArrow` gets printed correctly. If I uncomment the commented code I just get the following print:

```
height = sqrt(5000.000000) = 0.000000
```

Basically I always get 0 as output (this is the same behavior for the atan2 function that I'm using to calculate the angle). The `Arrow2D` method is called in one of my visualization functions called in the GLUT `display` method.

Comment: What compiler version are you using and what optimization options? Can you post the assembly output of the compiler for the function for both cases? (`-S -masm=intel` option for GCC, `-FAsc` for MSVC).

Comment: Your GL implementation could be messing with things like the FPU's rounding control word. Even if it is not, you should not be passing double-precision floating-point variables to `glVertex2f (...)`, OpenGL has a set of double-precision functions with the suffix `d`. Either use single-precision or use the appropriate GL API calls. A good compiler should be warning you for doing this.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: I'm using Visual Studio Express 2013, but unfortunately I have no idea how to provide you the output you requested. I'll get back to you when I know.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: Yeah, I forgot that. I'm using the glVertex2d function now (but still the bug is the same).

Comment: Do you actually include <GL/gl.h> in this piece of code? I'm guessing not, because otherwise the compiler would warn you that glPush/PopMatrix don't take any arguments. Since you have provided arguments, I'd guess that this is corrupting the stack or registers

Comment: @TheCodingMonk: to configure an assembly listing in Visual Studio, open the project properties and select the "C/C++ | Output Files | Assembler Output" item.  Change it to "Assembly, Machine Code, and Source (/FAcs)".  When you compile the file, it should produce a `*.cod` file with the assembly - copy/paste the assembly for the `Arrow2D()` function into the question.

Comment: @HughFisher Can you post that as an answer? It looks like it could be useful to future visitors.